# How to move all files in a subdir to another dir

Tags: linux, command-line, mv

I have untar wordpress. It creates a wordpress dir.

I want to move the files under this dir to mydomain.com dir but this doesn't work

```
mv wordpress/* mydomain.com
```

What's the syntax then ?

Thanks.

Comment: It should work. What is the error message that you get?

Comment: Did you create the 'mydomain.com' directory beforehand? If you haven't, it will __rename__ all the files to mydomain.com, and consequently, you will actually loose all your files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way, if the 'mydomain.com' directory doesn't exist yet, is actually to rename 'wordpress' into 'mydomain.com':

```
$ mv wordpress mydomain.com
```

If 'mydomain.com' already exists and you want to add the files from 'wordpress' to it, then:

```
$ mv wordpress/* mydomain.com/
```

should do.

Comment: mydomain already exists. When I try it says cannot move wordpress/wp-content to a subdirectory of itself, 'mydomain.com/wp-content' ?!!!

Comment: Hmm my target dir wasn't empty that is why :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to `mkdir mydomian.com` first before you run `mv wordpress/* mydomain.com`

Comment: But then he can just rename the folder.